# A correct use of the word "exchange"

Tags: attributive-nouns

Let's say I develop an internet site where producers can sell and consumers can buy flowers. I prefer to think of it as an exchange. From the point of view of native English speakers, which domain name would be more appropriate for the site: FLOWER.EXCHANGE or FLOWERS.EXCHANGE?

I have seen both notions of "commodity exchange" and "commodities exchanges", so am a little bit puzzled.

Thank you.

UPDATE: I can see that the "flower" in this case is called a noun adjunct, so it seems to be perfectly fine to use FLOWER.EXCHANGE. Just need a confirmation.

Comment: “Flower exchange” sounds good

Comment: You need the singular, not the plural. Shops stock multiple items of their goods but most refer to those goods in the singular when describing the shop. For instance "Bed shops", "carpet shops", "computer shops", "pet shops" and so on. Shoes are sold almost exclusively in pairs but the shops are still called "shoe shops". Finally a common alternative to "Florist" is "Flower Shop". You used to get "Car Spares Shops" but most of those were properly called "Car Accessory Shops".

Comment: Perhaps separately point out that your example is peculiar because the use of the word _commodities_ is slightly peculiar. In this meaning, it's vaguely like _scissors_ which only occurs in the plural.